# Android NDK CPU Macros. ARMv7

Tags: android, android-ndk, armv7

I found article that has following macros `__arm__`, `__i386__`

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/getting-started-on-optimizing-ndk-project-for-multiple-cpu-architectures

It has solution for ARMv7 detection.

But I would like detect that code was compiled for ARMv7 directly from CPP instead of using `Android.mk` to include different CPP files

I am not looking for cpufeatures
I am looking for target CPU for selected lib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for `__ARM_ARCH_7A__` macro.

Comment: Спасибо! Could you advice where can I find list of defines for Android NDK? When I search I find only source codes.

Comment: I don't know any good place where these defines are documented. But usually you can ask a compiler to print all predefined macro and google interesting names for the details. For example, following command will output defines available for armv7: `echo | arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -march=armv7-a -dM -E - | grep -i arm`

Comment: @AndreyKamaev: there is a lot of interesting flags to learn from running `ndk-build V=1`, which echoes all actual command lines it executes.

Comment: @AlexCohn Surely. There are a lot of them :)

Comment: cpu-features.h uses a number of them; somewhat useful as an example of what exists and what they mean.  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/libc/arch-arm/include/machine/cpu-features.h